# PHP: Is it possible to create a SplFileObject object from file contents (string)?

Tags: php, file, object

For example:

```
$contents = file_get_contents(image.png);
```

Is it possible to create a SplFileObject object from $contents?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you should clarify why you don't want to just do `new SplFileObject('image.png');`.

Comment: As I only have the file contents, I know finfo has the file_buffer method that can open string, I'm wondering does SplFileObject has the similar method or how can I convert string to a string buffer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

php has some [special stream wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) that let you re purpose the various file system functions

```
$contents = 'i am a string';
$file = 'php://memory'; //full memory buffering mode
//$file = 'php://temp/maxmemory:1048576'; //partial memory buffering mode. Tries to use memory, but over 1MB will automatically page the excess to a file.
$o = new SplFileObject($file, 'w+');
$o->fwrite($contents);
```

You don't need to use [SplFileObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) to use those wrappers though; you could use [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) instead.

Comment: I was trying to write to the `php://temp` then reading it as SplFIleObject, but your code shows something very important : you need to write to the wrapper after having created it in the SplFileObject.

Comment: @Benj you can reference open file descriptors by their id. eg `$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w'); $id = (int) $fp;` then to read `new SplFileObject("php://fd/$id", 'r')` might work. some info: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: @goat Thanks for the info, may be useful some day.

Comment: @goat One of my dependency package is saving the file in same way and then returning $o, but when i try to download/save using that file, i am getting empty file. Can you help me with the reason behind it ?