# File response from zip

Tags: php, file, zip, response

Here's what I am trying to do: I have created zip archive using [ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class with multiple files inside, what I need to do now, open archive, read single file and download or open it in browser.

Since I am using symfony2 framework, if it were a regular file, I could do something like this:

```
case 'open':
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filepath);
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filepath));
    $response->setContentDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE,
        $filename
    );
    return $response;
case 'save':
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filepath);
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filepath));
    $response->setContentDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $filename
    );
    return $response;
```

But since the file isn't in any directory I can pass it to BinaryFileResponse class because it accepts only string path to the file or SplFileInfo object, and not the file contents.

I found following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626532/php-is-it-possiable-create-a-splfileobject-object-from-a-file-contentsstring) which gave me idea to create SplFileObject from file contents and then pass it to BinaryFileResponse class as SplFileInfo object since SplFileObject extends SplFileInfo, so here's what I'v done:

```
$tmp = 'php://temp';
$file = new \SplFileObject($tmp, 'w+');
$file->fwrite($filecontents);
```

And then pass $file to BinaryFileResponse class, but it throws error: The file "php://temp" does not exist. I don't know if I am on the right way of doing something like this, and if so what I am missing.

In any case what I wan't to achieve is to serve file from archive in 2 different ways: 1. downlaod, 2.Open in browser.

PS. Those files are PDF format. And I can open them if I create response object and set it's content to that of a file from archive, but then I can't make it to download directly.

Sorry if it's confusing, and thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I eventually came up with:

```
//1. Extract file to chosen directory
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open('file/path/file.zip') {
    $zip->extractTo('chosen/directory', array('filename_in_zip_archive.ext'));
    $zip->close();
}

//2. Put file in response
$response = new Response(file_get_contents('chosen/directory/filename_in_zip_archive.ext'));
$mime = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$response->headers->set('Content-type', $mime->file('chosen/directory/filename_in_zip_archive.ext'));

//3. logic to open or download file
case 'open':
    $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE, 'filename_in_zip_archive.ext');
case 'save': 
    $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 'filename_in_zip_archive.ext');


//4. After file has been put to response, delete local file copy
if (file_exists('chosen/directory/filename_in_zip_archive.ext')) {
    unlink('chosen/directory/filename_in_zip_archive.ext');
}

//5. Return response with file
return $response;
```